# Saving positions of table cells that were moved using jquery and loading them into these positions after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have a school project right now to create a website.

This is the current project (don't mind it being german):
https://jsfiddle.net/MashiroShiina/w08czoLv/18/

The javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#anfrage, #annahme, #bearbeitung, #abschluss, #auftraege").sortable({
    connectWith: ".projektgeneral",
    remove: function(e, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var childs = $this.find('div');
      if (childs.length === 0) {
        $this.text("");
      }
    },
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
      }).remove();
    },
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

You can drag & drop the 2 Projects into different categories.

We are fairly new to javascript and tried finding anything related to this, but our problem is the following:

We have a SQL database on the same host and we want to be able to save the positions of the moved "Projects" on our database, so that when we reload the page, they are still in the same spot we left them in.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: What I understood is you want to store the positions of your items (project names in your case) so that you can retrieve it back when user refreshes the page, if that is so., I would recommend to use **cookies** or **localstorage** instead of SQL database. SQL is an overkill for such trivial task. And for localstorage you could refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: and for referring to your storing positions scenario, take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/v685v9t6/)